# Class library extension methods, this keyword not pointing to the right source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a class library that contains a couple of extensions methods classes. The problem I am facing at the moment is when I try to invoke an extension method from another project that is referencing the library it doesn't compile unless I pass the extended class as parameter.

*function definition*

```
  public static MvcHtmlString Tooltip(this HtmlHelper @this, string tooltip)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString($@" <i class=""fa fa-question-circle"" title=""{tooltip}""></i>");
    }
```

*the expected way of making a function call*

```
  MyLibrary.Extensions.Tooltip("foo")
```

*the problem I have (the only way it compiles)*

```
  MyLibrary.Extensions.Tooltip(HtmlHelper,"foo")
```

Comment: That's not how extension methods are supposed to work... Where's the instance of `HtmlHelper`?

Comment: Omit the `this`-keyword for a try. How would you call the static method then? You need an instance of type `HtmlHelper` as per the methods signature.

Comment: Is your first example "MyLibrary.Extensions.Tooltip("foo")" used on an instance variable of type HtmlHelper? If so, please include the whole line of code just to make sure.

Comment: I do have an instance of HtmlHelper, but I can't see the functions from the library if use that instance, only the internal ones.

Comment: I guess this is because `HtmlHelper` indicates both an instance and the type. This is why compiler is confused if you mean your instance or the class. Try to rename your variable and see if it works then.

Answer (score 1):

An extension method *extends* some other class.
So in your case, given a variable `Html` of type `HtmlHelper`, you can call `Html.Tooltip("foo")`.

You do need a `using MyLibrary.Extensions;` in the file where you want to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods *extend* close types, so calling them as a static method is not how the use is intended.

You should be able to call:

```
HtmlHelper.Tooltip("foo")
```

Or even:

```
@Html.Tooltip("foo")
```

Make sure though the namespace is configured as `using` correctly: either in your view or from the `web.config`.

Comment: "`HtmlHelper.Tooltip("foo")`"  won´t compile unless `HtmlHelper` was an instance of type `HtmlHelper`.

Comment: Which it seems to be looking at OPs code `MyLibrary.Extensions.Tooltip(HtmlHelper,"foo")`, which was *the only way it compiles*.

Comment: It still shouldn't compile if not given an HtmlHelper object - be it through the first argument, or by calling it as an extension method on top of an instance variable. With "MyLibrary.Extensions.Tooltip("foo")" OP only shows a method call with 1 parameter only, obviously it should fail, unless OP omitted the part where he calls it on an instance variable.

Comment: I guess OP expected the `this` to be derived from the calling `this`, not the instance called upon. @nikovn